# Isolating I/O issue with NVME or hardware?

Tags: ubuntu, hardware, io, ssd, nvme

Hardware:

- Samsung 980 PRO M.2 NVMe SSD (MZ-V8P2T0BW) (2TB)
- Beelink GTR6, with the SSD in the NVMe slot

Since the hardware arrived, I've installed Ubuntu Server on it as well as a bunch of services (mostly in docker, DBs and services like Kafka).

After 2-3 days of uptime (record is almost a week, but usually it's 2-3 days), I typically start getting buffer i/o errors on the nvme slot (which is also the boot drive):
[image: screen1]

If I'm quick enough, I can still login via SSH but the system becomes increasingly unstable before commands start failing with an I/O error. When I did manage to login, it did seem to think there's no connected NVME SSDs:
[image: screen2]

Another instance of the buffer I/O error on the nvme slot:
[image: screen3]

Because of this and trying to check everything I could find, I ran FSCK on boot to see if there was anything obvious - this is quite common after the hard reset:

```
# cat  /run/initramfs/fsck.log
Log of fsck -C -f -y -V -t ext4 /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
Fri Dec 30 17:26:21 2022

fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
[/usr/sbin/fsck.ext4 (1) -- /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv] fsck.ext4 -f -y -C0 /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: recovering journal
Clearing orphaned inode 524449 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100664, size=6216)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Inode 6947190 extent tree (at level 1) could be shorter.  Optimize? yes

Inode 6947197 extent tree (at level 1) could be shorter.  Optimize? yes

Inode 6947204 extent tree (at level 1) could be shorter.  Optimize? yes

Inode 6947212 extent tree (at level 1) could be shorter.  Optimize? yes

Inode 6947408 extent tree (at level 1) could be shorter.  Optimize? yes

Inode 6947414 extent tree (at level 1) could be shorter.  Optimize? yes

Inode 6947829 extent tree (at level 1) could be shorter.  Optimize? yes

Inode 6947835 extent tree (at level 1) could be shorter.  Optimize? yes

Inode 6947841 extent tree (at level 1) could be shorter.  Optimize? yes

Pass 1E: Optimizing extent trees
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Free blocks count wrong (401572584, counted=405399533).
Fix? yes

Free inodes count wrong (121360470, counted=121358242).
Fix? yes


/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: 538718/121896960 files (0.2% non-contiguous), 82178067/487577600 blocks
fsck exited with status code 1

Fri Dec 30 17:26:25 2022
----------------
```

Running smart-log doesn't seem to show anything concerning, other than the number of unsafe shutdowns (the number of times this has happened so far)...

```
# nvme smart-log /dev/nvme0
Smart Log for NVME device:nvme0 namespace-id:ffffffff
critical_warning                        : 0
temperature                                : 32 C (305 Kelvin)
available_spare                                : 100%
available_spare_threshold                : 10%
percentage_used                                : 0%
endurance group critical warning summary: 0
data_units_read                                : 8,544,896
data_units_written                        : 5,175,904
host_read_commands                        : 39,050,379
host_write_commands                        : 191,366,905
controller_busy_time                        : 1,069
power_cycles                                : 21
power_on_hours                                : 142
unsafe_shutdowns                        : 12
media_errors                                : 0
num_err_log_entries                        : 0
Warning Temperature Time                : 0
Critical Composite Temperature Time        : 0
Temperature Sensor 1           : 32 C (305 Kelvin)
Temperature Sensor 2           : 36 C (309 Kelvin)
Thermal Management T1 Trans Count        : 0
Thermal Management T2 Trans Count        : 0
Thermal Management T1 Total Time        : 0
Thermal Management T2 Total Time        : 0
```

I have reached out to support and their initial suggestion along with a bunch of questions was whether I had tried to reinstall the OS. I've given this a go too, formatting the drive and reinstalling the OS (Ubuntu Server 22 LTS).

After that, the issue hadn't happened for 4 days before it finally showed itself as a kernel panic:
[image]

Any ideas what I can do to identify if the problem is with the SSD itself or the hardware that the SSD is slotted into (the GTR6)? I have until the 31st to return the SSD, so would love to pin down the most likely cause of the issue sooner rather than later...

I'm even more concerned after seeing reports that others are having serious health issues with the Samsung 990 Pro:
https://www.reddit.com/r/hardware/comments/10jkwwh/samsung_990_pro_ssd_with_rapid_health_drops/

Edit: although I realised those reported issues are with the 990 pro, not the 980 pro that I have!

Edit2: someone in overclockers was kind enough to suggest hd sentinel, which does show a health metric, which seems ok:

```
# ./hdsentinel-019c-x64       
Hard Disk Sentinel for LINUX console 0.19c.9986 (c) 2021 info@hdsentinel.com
Start with -r [reportfile] to save data to report, -h for help

Examining hard disk configuration ...
HDD Device  0: /dev/nvme0             
HDD Model ID : Samsung SSD 980 PRO 2TB
HDD Serial No: S69ENL0T905031A
HDD Revision : 5B2QGXA7
HDD Size     : 1907729 MB
Interface    : NVMe
Temperature  : 41 °C
Highest Temp.: 41 °C
Health       : 99 %
Performance  : 100 %
Power on time: 21 days, 12 hours
Est. lifetime: more than 1000 days
Total written: 8.30 TB
  The status of the solid state disk is PERFECT. Problematic or weak sectors were not found. 
  The health is determined by SSD specific S.M.A.R.T. attribute(s):  Available Spare (Percent), Percentage Used
    No actions needed.
```

Lastly, none of the things I tried such as the smart-log seem to show something like a health metric. How can I check this in ubuntu?

Thanks!

Comment: A USB enclosure can probably help you to confirm whether or not the drive itself is okay. However, it will not confirm whether or not it has something to do the nvme driver in the kernel, since you'll be using the uas driver then.

Comment: *it did seem to think there's no connected NVME SSDs*  You probably have bad hardware.  Somewhere.  First step is to make sure everything is seated properly.  And that means everything.  First thing I'd do after making sure everything is seated properly is get a known-good NVME SSD, put that into the system, and start testing it pretty hard.  And if possible put the Samsung 980 into another system that's known-good and test it on that system.  See which one fails.  Intermittent hardware problems are always fun *fun* **fun**.

Comment: if simply re-seating the nvme does not help, buy a cheap nvme and test with it. if it has the same issues, probably an issue with the nvme slot. you could check your syslog (or enable network logging) to catch the first message in the whole chain of errors that follows.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Beelink accepted a return for replacement, hopefully this will just be a one-off problem on the hardware I've received from beelink!

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue, with disappearing device...
Immediately after boot it's usually there, but it somehow gives reason for the kernel (or driver) to think it's disappearing.

When I did a complete block check in Windows, it just stayed up the whole 14+ hours, and had 0% bad blocks... My drive is just a month old, so I expect the hardware to still be good, it must be a driver or motherboard/bios interaction issue...

Example output:

```
[  646.205010] nvme nvme1: I/O 526 QID 2 timeout, aborting
[  646.205039] nvme nvme1: I/O 213 QID 5 timeout, aborting
[  646.264489] nvme nvme1: Abort status: 0x0
[  646.351285] nvme nvme1: Abort status: 0x0
[  676.924830] nvme nvme1: I/O 526 QID 2 timeout, reset controller
[  697.972569] nvme nvme1: Device not ready; aborting reset, CSTS=0x1
[  697.993956] pcieport 10000:e0:1b.0: can't derive routing for PCI INT A
[  697.993965] nvme 10000:e2:00.0: PCI INT A: no GSI
[  709.369577] wlp45s0: AP e0:cc:7a:98:7d:d4 changed bandwidth, new config is 2432.000 MHz, width 2 (2442.000/0 MHz)
[  718.496375] nvme nvme1: Device not ready; aborting reset, CSTS=0x1
[  718.496381] nvme nvme1: Removing after probe failure status: -19
[  739.020199] nvme nvme1: Device not ready; aborting reset, CSTS=0x1
[  739.020477] nvme1n1: detected capacity change from 2000409264 to 0
```

Now I have tried this: `echo 10000:e2:00.0 >/sys/bus/pci/drivers/nvme/bind`

When I then do `lspci` the "missing" device is enumerated correctly (10000:e2:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: ADATA Technology Co., Ltd. Device 5766 (rev 01))

But it doesn't show up in `lsblk` and I don't know how to proceed from here...

The dmesg output after re-binding the drive:

```
[14893.259570] nvme nvme2: pci function 10000:e2:00.0
[14893.259678] pcieport 10000:e0:1b.0: can't derive routing for PCI INT A
[14893.259685] nvme 10000:e2:00.0: PCI INT A: no GSI
[14913.760764] nvme nvme2: Device not ready; aborting reset, CSTS=0x1
[14913.760771] nvme nvme2: Removing after probe failure status: -19
```

Eventually I got a new module, put it in the same slot (replacing the old one), and it is all working normally.

Conclusion: [highly likely] a bad NVMe stick. This happens, and I bet it was the same on your setup.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/441510)

Comment: At the moment I'm suspecting a hardware issue with the server this device is in. I've gone through the process of returning it for a replacement, and as before, the issue came back after a week on the new device as well. Maybe I'll try a second ssd of the exact same specs, in case that's related...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).